# Remove all content filtering from TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

I'm working on an email client within an HTML web application and am using TinyMCE as the text editor.  One of my requirements is to allow the input of full HTML email creatives and am attempting to paste them into the source code input.  When I do this however and save it, TinyMCE appears to be removing a lot of the code from the pasted creative, for example the `doctype` tag, `html` tags, entire `head` section (including inline CSS), and various other tags for example `tbody` etc.

I've also noticed that the text within the `title` tag has been put inside `p` tags at the start of the document.

Ideally I'd prefer to have the ability to paste the full document and not have any of the source altered, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is the code I'm using to initialise TinyMCE:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.js-email-editor',
    plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak legacyoutput',
        'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code',
        'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
        'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools codesample toc help'
    ],
    toolbar1: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
    toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | codesample help',
    image_advtab: true,
    content_css: [
        '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
        '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
    ],
    branding: false,
    valid_elements: '*[*]'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fullpage` plugin will allow TinyMCE to work with a full HTML page of content.  By default, you are working with items inside the `<body>` tag of an HTML document.  Running the `fullpage` plugin will allow you to work with the entire page.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/fullpage/

Comment: Thanks, this has got me a step closer to where I want to be, however the html is still getting rendered differently and slightly changed.  The HTML sent via the email is still not a match to my input HTML

Comment: TinyMCE does some cleanup and validation of the HTML...there is no setting to completely eliminate this step.

Answer (score 0):

In "Tools" tab in menu you can switch to "Source code". Paste your code as the source code and then go back to WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Yeh, this is what I've done, when I paste a full html document into here and press 'ok' it removes a lot of the markup as I mentioned above